# Regex - Why are the named groups located at the end of the group array?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, text

Why are the named groups located at the end of the group array?

Pattern for example (with named and unnamed groups):

```
(?<digit>\d+)\|(?<main>\d+)\|(\d+)\|(?<abc>\d+)\|(\d+)
```

And text:

```
123|456|789|10|11
```

Why "789" and "11" located at the beginning of array?

[image]

See demo [systemtextregularexpressions.com](http://www.systemtextregularexpressions.com/regex.match?p=KD88ZGlnaXQ%2BXGQrKVx8KD88bWFpbj5cZCspXHwoXGQrKVx8KD88YWJjPlxkKylcfChcZCsp&t=MTIzfDQ1Nnw3ODl8MTB8MTE%3D)

Sorry for my english :)

Comment: 0, 1, 2, digit, main,**ABC** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... it's simply an implementation choice made in the .NET Framework.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.getgroupnumbers.aspx) explains the algorithm:

> Both unnamed and named capturing groups can be accessed by number. Unnamed groups are numbered from left to right starting with 1. (The capturing group in index 0 (zero) represents the match as a whole.) **Named groups are then numbered from left to right starting with a number that is one greater than the number of unnamed capturing groups.**

The same does not necessarily apply for other flavors, for instance PCRE assigns group numbers in the order they appear in the pattern whether they're named or not.

Comment: Both approaches are valid IMO, and each regex implementation has to make a choice. Personally, I wouldn't mix named and unnamed groups anyway. Pick either one. This clears up the confusion.